# List contacts in category Joomla

Tags: php, css, joomla, joomla2.5, contacts

I have an issue with Joomla 2.5 "List contacts in a category" menu item. I can't change sorting. I tried already to change ordering, menu item settings, change ids of contacts in category, but the changes don't appear in front end.

Then I made new category of contacts and tried to make new menu item with new category when I made new contacts, but in front end appears old category.

I seem like this category is fixed in some php files. How do I change the ordering? Where can it be fixed in the php files?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be you a simple case of having the system cache on? Turn it off if so.
 Global Configuration>SYSTEM>Cache Settings...